# Calling AddView in a JavaScriptInterface class

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to add a textview dynamically to a linear layout. But there is a problem.

In my button, this code works very well:

```
TextView ASDF = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.note_date, null);
ASDF.setText("TEST");
HomeContainer.addView(ASDF);
```

But when I try to add this view in a function which called by a JavaScriptInterface class, it does not work. I am using @JavaScriptInterface in order to get my webview's page source. And briefly, I am trying to add new textviews to my layout when web page is loaded in my webview.

So it is like:

```
public class WebAppInterface
{
     Context mContext;
     WebAppInterface(Context c) {mContext = c;}

     @JavascriptInterface
     public void GetHTML(String html)
     {
         ...
         ...
         TextView ASDF = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.note_date, null);
         ASDF.setText("TEST");
         HomeContainer.addView(ASDF);
     }
}
```

When I check, I see that webview's source is correct, and also ASDF is not returned null by inflate(), then problem is about addView, I think.

How can I fix that problem?

**EDIT:**
Tried this one, did not work:

```
TextView ASDF = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.note_nick, null);
ASDF.setText("TEST");
((MainActivity)this.getParent()).HomeContainer.addView(ASDF);
```

---

**EDIT:**

**Solved, Thanks to @SimonSays, This will solve your problem:**

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                TextView ASDF = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.note_date, null);
                ASDF.setText("TEST");
                HomeContainer.addView(ASDF);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is the value of `HomeContainer` correct at that point?

Comment: Yes, HomeContainer is a LinearLayout and correct. At that point, when I click my button, it adds a new TextView. But when I refresh webview, it gets source but does not add TextView. So annoying. Also I tried that one,   TextView A = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.note_nick, null); ((Home)this.getParent()).HomeContainer.addView(A);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the JavaScript method is not executed in the UI thread. Only this thread can modify the UI. You can either use [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [View.post()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to do so.

Comment: Wow thank you man! Can't vote since I don't have enough reputation!